# Spring boot integration test error: "Could not resolve placeholder 'wiremock.server.port'" in tests not requiring Wiremock

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, wiremock

I have a `@SpringBootTest` which tests the loading of a `@ConfigurationProperties` and its methods. It is in `test` source set.

And, in `itest`, I have an integration test which uses Wiremock(sending requests and using stubs as response, etc.)

Now, when I run `gradle test`, the first test fails, saying:

> [ENV=local] [productName=app-gateway-api] [2019-10-22T16:18:30.994Z] [ERROR] [MSG=[Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController' defined in file [E:\coding\code\app\build\classes\java\main\com\app\controller\MyController> .class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'proxyService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'wiremock.server.port' in value
>   "http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}/send"

Which is used in some external properties. The value will be used in `itest`, but not in `test`. But the context loads it always.

In other projects using it like this, there is no problem. But, it seems that it is loading all the classes and cannot find Wiremock and create the server.

The test in problem:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class MapperLookupTest {
    ...
}
```

Wiremock dependency already has `compile` scope:

```
    compile('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.21.0')
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner")
```

I have tried to load only the necessary classes with `@SpringBootTest(classes = {...})`, but it is too verbose.

So, is there any easy way to tell the context to load Wiremock?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a default value to your placeholder:

```
${wiremock.server.port:defaultValue}
```

Comment: Ah you mean in the yaml file. OK that is something I didn't know. Thanks. At last I use `@SpringBootTest(properties = "wiremock.server.port=8080")`, much the same.

Answer (score -1):

At last I decide not to honor @Cwrwhaf, sorry.. because I don't want to have a possible negative impact on the production code; I just want to pass the test and any changes should be limited to the mere scope of the test itself.

So I did:

```java
@SpringBootTest(property = "wiremock.server.port=8080")
```

And I am aware of the fact that it is not the perfect answer, but has less impact than changing global settings of wiremock.